# SharePoint 2013 Search Crawl Paused by the System

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

Every few days or so I go into my search service application and I see that my content source says:

> paused by the system

This appears in my three environments DEV/UAT/PROD randomly. Has anyone had this problem and been able to figure it out? I don't even know how I would troubleshoot it at I am not sure when exactly this occurs. I saw something about Symantec Backup Exec causing the issue but we've disabled it and it's still happening. We're also using Symantec Backup Exec 2012 where they've already provided a fix.

Comment: Have you ever looked at the logs in the Central Administration?

Comment: I have looked in the ULS logs and have not found anything significant. The problem is that I don't have an idea what time this is happening. In the meantime I have decided run a Powershell script that starts the content source every morning using a scheduled task